# Extra characters while reading file path

Tags: python, xlrd

i am using this code to read all files in the directory with ".xlsx" extension and upload data from them to a database. while reading the file i am getting some additional charachters in the file name.

```
C:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\UCP DATA\Cloud Based Entry Test Praparator\Project Files\Database\Python Scripts\Upload Data to database\Data Files\NTS-IM-PHYSICS.xlsx
C:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\UCP DATA\Cloud Based Entry Test Praparator\Project Files\Database\Python Scripts\Upload Data to database\Data Files\NTS-QUANTATIVE.xlsx
C:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\UCP DATA\Cloud Based Entry Test Praparator\Project Files\Database\Python Scripts\Upload Data to database\Data Files\~$ECAT-CHEMISTRY.xlsx
```

the last line in the above has "~$" just before the filename at the end. i tried deleting that file and creating again. it just happens to the last file that is read. and due to this i get this error stack i have put in the end.

```
datafiles = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Data Files")
for r, d, f in os.walk(datafiles):
    for file in f:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            header, data = read(os.path.join(r, file))
            for i in range(1, len(data)):
                insertRow(mydb, mycursor, data[i], file)
                totalRows+=1
                print("FileName: {} | Row: {} | Total: {}".format(file, i, totalRows))
```

My Read Function:

```
def read(file_name):
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    print(file_name)
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col=None, header=None) 
    df1 = df.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
    data = df1.values.tolist()
    header = data[0]
    return header, data
```

Error Trace:

```
C:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\UCP DATA\Cloud Based Entry Test Praparator\Project Files\Database\Python Scripts\Upload Data to database\Data Files\~$ECAT-CHEMISTRY.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\UCP DATA\Cloud Based Entry Test Praparator\Project Files\Database\Python Scripts\Upload Data to database\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    header, data = read(os.path.join(r, file))
  File "c:\Users\Haseeb\Desktop\UCP DATA\Cloud Based Entry Test Praparator\Project Files\Database\Python Scripts\Upload Data to database\readXLSXFile.py", line 5, in read
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col=None, header=None)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 867, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 37, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 148, in open_workbook
    bk = book.open_workbook_xls(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 92, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1278, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1272, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x06Haseeb '
```

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to call `os.getcwd()` to get the full path to the current directory unless you specifically require all file names to be absolute paths for external reasons. Python (and generally any program in any language) resolves relative file names from the current working directory; this is an OS-level guarantee.

Comment: yes thats a good tip. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an [owner file](https://superuser.com/questions/1190986/office-files) and is created automatically when you open an Office file. You should probably ignore those in your code unless you have a specific reason to read them.

Comment: i see, how do i exclude this file? if "~$" in file: ?

Comment: I would probably get the file name component only and check the first character, so something like `os.path.split(file_name)[1][0] == '~'`